# What to test when building an MVC framework in PHP?

Tags: testing, model-view-controller, phpunit

I am building an MVC framework in PHP, grasping all the object oriented concepts and patterns. I know this sounds broad, but I don't know where to start testing? I know I could test if a database connection is successful or not, but other than that I don't know when to test. I am using PHPUnit.

Comment: Test routing, HTTP abstraction, DI container, autoloading (if you are not using Composer's), caching mechanism, unit of work templates. Here is the point that you probably have missed: **you cannot make an MVC framework.** The MVC architectural pattern is not implemented by a framework but by the application. Then again .. what the hell I know about any of this *(queue the laravel and codeigniter fanboys)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to test:

1. Unit tests only instantiate one class at best, all dependent classes get mocked, and you then call all the methods of that one class and try to provide parameters that make the class get into `if` and `else` cases as much as possible. You should probably start with this way and pick one class that you have. Pick a class that uses NO other class for operation, i.e. no database, no `new Otherclass` inside, no classes as parameters for `__construct`.
2. The next level probably are integration test. These put a bunch of classes together and test some common interactions. This might be using an existing database to test a database layer, or a real filesystem, but is not meant to be a full application.
3. The probably last level is functional testing. This really is targeted a a fully deployed application, and might use things like virtual browsers used by Selenium to test the complete GUI. For API applications this usually means having a deployed HTTP server being tested with real HTTP requests.

You should start with unit tests.

Answer (score -2):

First check the phpunit is correctly installed or not and in your codeigniter folder just put an test.php file like post_controller.php as post_controllerTest.php and test using this method (Use PhpStorm)

Comment: I am building my own MVC framework and don't know what to test as the controllers. That doesn't help me.

Comment: Nobody ever mentioned "Codeigniter" here. This answer is not adressing the question.